# SQL multiple columns with text

Tags: sql

I'm having a small problem here with SQL.

I need to find out which movie has got 2 genres

```
SELECT v.explanation
FROM v, g
WHERE   
    g.Video_ID = v.Video_ID AND  
    g.Explanation= "Genre1" AND  
    g.Explanation= "Genre2";
```

It returns null, when I use only one it works of course.

Answer (score 1):

First, always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Then, you can solve your problem using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT v.Bezeichnung  
FROM video v JOIN
     hat_genre g   
     ON g.Video_ID = v.Video_ID  
WHERE g.Bezeichnung IN ('Horror', 'Thriller')
GROUP BY v.Bezeichnung
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT g.Bezeichnung) = 2;
```

Additional Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The ANSI-standard SQL delimiter for strings is a single quote; this is preferable to a double quote which can have other meanings.
- `IN` is the most efficient way to test for multiple values.